# How can I share internet from wireless enabled netbook to a wired desktop PC

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, netbook, wired

I have got a netbook which has a wireless card. How can I share that internet from netbook to a desktop PC which does not have wireless card. I suppose I can do it somehow over USB (I am not sure if my netbook can act as a USB hub ...) or LAN?

Any directions please!

Comment: What OS is on the netbook?

Comment: Windows 7 Starter on the netbook and Windows 7 Ultimate on the desktop.

Comment: I have never tried it with that configuration, but you can have more than one net device. With any ol wireless USB thing, you could probably use virtual router (software).  You can "bridge" (often concidered a bad idea and probably not with starter). You can ICS (internet connection sharing) but I do not think you can do that at all with starter OSes. You could put in a USB NIC item and share wired, but not without software to interconnect. You could put in some bluetooth junk, and deal with the fact that without good BT software you cant do anything :-)   Connections possible software needed.

Comment: Its very easy with netsh commands: Here is a link do turn win7 into wifi hotspot, just revert the process to share thru ethernet port: [http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Set-Up-a-Wireless-Hotspot-Windows-7/](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Set-Up-a-Wireless-Hotspot-Windows-7/)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 Starter edition had the Internet Connection Sharing utility removed from the menus, however, I'm told it is still there. Just go to the Start menu and type "adhoc" to get to it.

*(citing [gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/5421088/get-internet-connection-sharing-in-windows-7-starter-in-one-easy-step) on that one, I haven't tried it myself due to a lack of convenient Starter edition PCs here...)*

With ICS and a cheap switch, you should be able to get this all wired up. Connect ethernet ports on both laptops to the switch, then get the wifi on the netbook connected. Once connected, run "adhoc" and get ICS configured to share that wifi connection to the ethernet clients.

See [Using ICS](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing) for some more details.